# Android Firebase List Adapters Constructor Error

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-listview

I'm trying to create a list view with the data from the Firebase real time database.For some reason I am keep getting a red line under this code.Hope you can let me know what is my mistake here. Thank you :). I have attached my layout file and also my app gradle codes.

```
(this,String.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,databaseReference)

Below here is the complete code

            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://vsem-inventory.firebaseio.com/");
        FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this,String.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,databaseReference) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull String model, int position) {
                TextView textView = v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            }
        };

        mListView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

content_main_menu.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainMenu">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

App gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.vseminventory"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: Can you please state the error which is encountered

Comment: It just states compilation error

Comment: Please share the entire code of the activity including your gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using the new Firebaseui (version 3.0+), the constructor of the `FirebaseListAdapter` was changed.

First, you need to configure the adapter by using the class `FirebaseListOptions`, then you can create an instance of `FirebaseListAdapter`.

Check this code from the docs:

```
 FirebaseListOptions<Chat> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Chat>()
    .setQuery(query, Chat.class)
    .build();

FirebaseListAdapter<Chat> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Chat>(options) {
@Override
protected void populateView(View v, Chat model, int position) {
    // Bind the Chat to the view
    // ...
 }
};
```

As you can see the `FirebaseListAdapter` takes a parameter of type `FirebaseListOptions`

More info here:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-listview

---

You can see the source code here:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseListAdapter.java

Comment: What do i change the query in .setQuery (query,...) with?

Comment: `SetQuery(databaseReference, String.class)`

Comment: Don't forget to read the docs linked in the answer and add `startListening()` and `stopListening()`

Comment: @Blacky_99 did the answer help you?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, my app compiles but it crashes. :(